# Chiral elastic solids

Tags: elasticity, chirality

[image: In the first picture, these two equations have C1, C2, and C3 constants(picture 1)]

[image: this is the second picture(picture2)]

Equations in these two pictures are similar, but in the second pictures, the author set the C1, C2 of the equations to be zero and get the final equation shown in picture 2

My question is why the equations in picture 2, the parameter: C1 and C2 are zero?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please actually type out the relevant text you are interested instead of posting pictures of it. Not all users can access pictures. For equations and variables, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Please also add the bibliographic information of the text.